# Reelegido vs reelecto

Tags: verbos, conjugación, gerundio

Recientemente leí un par de artículos políticos donde aparecían las siguientes frases:

> ... el candiato será reelegido.
>   ... está tratando de ser reelegido.

Según yo, en ambos casos la forma correcta es reelecto, pero al verlo en más de una ocasión me han hecho dudar.

¿Es correcta la forma como se esta usando la conjugación en los artículos que lei? Si es el caso, ¿cuándo es correcto usar "reelecto"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la 1ª edición (2005) del *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas*, la forma correcta del participio de *[elegir](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=elegir)* sería la regular *elegido*, mientras que *electo* es una forma tradicional que debería usarse sólo como adjetivo:

> La forma *electo* (del part. lat. *electus*), considerada
>   tradicionalmente participio irregular de *elegir*, es un adjetivo que
>   significa ‘que ha sido elegido para una dignidad o cargo y aún no ha
>   tomado posesión’ (...). Por lo tanto, **no debe utilizarse** este adjetivo
>   para formar los tiempos compuestos o la pasiva perifrástica de
>   *elegir* (...).

Es decir, se puede usar *electo* cuando significa “que ha sido elegido pero todavía no ha tomado posesión”, como adjetivo que modifica el nombre de la dignidad o cargo en cuestión (por ejemplo, *presidente electo*, *directora electa*). No se puede usar como parte tiempos verbales compuestos o de perífrasis verbales como la voz pasiva. Lo mismo debe valer, obviamente, para *reelegir*, *reelegido* y *reelecto*.

Hasta ahí el DLE. Sin embargo, ante la [constatación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30677/14627) de que *reelecto* sigue figurando como "participio irregular" de *reelegir* en el DLE, consulté con el servicio de resolución de dudas que la RAE atiende por Twitter ([@RAEInforma](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma)). La [respuesta](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1138407487823056896) me remitió a un [recorte](http://static.ow.ly/docs/elegido-electo_6ATH.pdf) de un avance de la próxima edición del DLE donde se aclara que

1. En España solo se emplea como participio la forma regular *elegido*.
2. En el español americano, aunque en general predomina el uso
   del participio regular, se usa a menudo el irregular *electo* para formar la pasiva perifrástica (“Fue electo alcalde...”).
3. Es menos frecuente y, por ello, desaconsejable utilizar *electo* en la formación de los tiempos compuestos; es preferible decir “Lo han elegido presidente” que “Lo han electo presidente.”

Nótese que se recurre a la frecuencia de uso como medida de lo que aconsejable que es ese mismo uso.

En esta pregunta lidiamos con pasivas perifrásticas (“el candidato será reelegido/reelecto” o “está tratando de ser reelegido/reelecto”), de manera que se aplica la consideración especial del punto 2: entre hablantes de español americano, sonará bien cualquiera de los dos participios. Entre hablantes de España es mejor usar *reelegido*.

Comment: Wow, veo que llegamos a respuestas distintas, citando a la misma autoridad... a estas alturas, habrá que hacer un compendio de las contradicciones de la RAE

Comment: Vi tu respuesta un segundo después de haber publicado la mía, de lo contrario te habría dejado la primicia... :) Acabo de preguntarle a la RAE sobre esto, veremos qué dice.

Comment: Una hipótesis es que el tratamiento fuera distinto entre _elegir_ y _reelegir_, que no me parece demasiado descabellado, ahora que lo pienso

Comment: @pablodf76 - Está complicado establecer cual de las dos respuestas es la mejor candidata para ser la aceptada :) ¿Podrías agregar a tu respuesta una vez que te responda la RAE, ojalá lo haga, por favor?

Comment: @SergioRomero Ya está agregado (a partir de donde dice "Hasta aquí el DLE.").

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son correctas, según el Diccionario de la Lengua Española.

En efecto, **[reelegir](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VaocCtg)** es uno de esos verbos a los que se les reconoce dos participios, uno irregular (de origen arcaico traído más directamente del Latín) y otro regular (que se deriva de aplicar reglas más comúnes para verbos similares), que poco a poco ha ido quitando terreno al anterior. Esto es lo que dice la entrada del DLE:

[image]

En algún momento de la historia del castellano, sólo el irregular fue correcto, pero el uso del participio regular se ha hecho tan común que ha impulsado a la RAE a reconocerlo como válido también.

Esta tendencia a la regularización de palabras es un proceso común, no sólo en castellano. [Este artículo](http://news.mit.edu/2007/language-1015) da cuenta del proceso análogo en inglés, y cómo han logrado medirlo y estimar su evolución futura (incluso dan un ejemplo ingenuo de cuál sería el próximo verbo en *regularizarse*).

Comment: Muy interesante el paper citado. Ojalá tuviéramos algo similar en castellano.